# Android 12 - PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL intent never received

Tags: android, android-device-owner

We are migrating our Device policy app to Android 12 last API. during our test we notice that the intent **PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL** was never received so the related activity never started , instead of that **ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE** is well received in our admin receiver.

The documentation and comment in the aosp source says that :

> PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL Action is sent to indicate that provisioning of a managed profile or managed device has completed successfully.
> It'll be sent at the same time as DeviceAdminReceiver#ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE  broadcast but this will be delivered faster as it's an activity intent.

ProvisioningSuccessActivity entry in manifest :

```
    <activity
      android:exported="true"
      android:name=".ProvisioningSuccessActivity"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I'm wondering if someone encountered the same issue ? thanks

Comment: i opened an issue on the  google  issue tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201968957

Comment: Have you found a fix to this issue yet ? We are also facing this same issue

Answer (score 0):

From Android 12, you will need to include the new changes to support provisioning as DPC.
https://developer.android.google.cn/work/versions/android-12#deprecations
Follow the steps given here https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices#set_up_device_owner_mode_google_account.

Answering to the question on the reason for PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL never received, it is expected as per the flow. The documentation from Android is not updated to reflect the behaviour.
Please refer to the source code https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.1.0_r8:packages/apps/ManagedProvisioning/src/com/android/managedprovisioning/finalization/ProvisioningIntentProvider.java;l=48
where we can confirm that ComplianceScreen is launched instead of ProvisioningSuccessful Screen if the setup is part of setup wizard.

Comment: @issamux please see my updated answer for the query on PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score -1):

I believe Karthi Keyan is right

As is said by a contributor to the google testing app for provisioning, the famous [testdpc](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc)

They migrated all entry points to provisioning to use intents

android.app.action.GET_PROVISIONING_MODE and android.app.action.ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/issues/133#issuecomment-944367382

I also need to migrate the EMM app to suit Android 12 and I will adopt this approach

Comment: in our code the migration to GET_PROVISIONING_MODE and ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE is already done and working... my question is about PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL intent that should come at the end of provisioning process.
Instead of this ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE is received , please read again my question